# What method to create auto slideshow images in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've seen some people used replace function by click bullet but i don't understand why have to use replace function and how it works maybe there's a better way ?

1. How can i use for loop to make bullet show image and when we clicked
   on any bullet,that bullet will change color?(but not exact like
   hover) I actually already created clicked class in css but i don't know how
   to make it works.
2. Finally,What method to use for auto slide images?

```js
var sliderImages = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
var arrowLeft = document.querySelector('#arrow-left');
var arrowRight = document.querySelector('#arrow-right');
var arrowSlide = document.querySelectorAll('.arrow');
var sliderBullets = document.querySelectorAll('.bullets');
var current = 0;

//reset slideimages
function resetSlide() {
    for (var i = 0; i < sliderImages.length; i++) {
        sliderImages[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}

//slide left
arrowLeft.addEventListener('click', function () {
    resetSlide();
    if (current === 0) {
        current = sliderImages.length;
    }
    sliderImages[current - 1].style.display = 'block';
    current--;
});

//slide right
arrowRight.addEventListener('click', function () {
    resetSlide();
    if (current === sliderImages.length - 1) {
        current = -1;
    }
    sliderImages[current + 1].style.display = 'block';
    current++;
});

//start slide
function startSlide() {
    resetSlide();
    sliderImages[0].style.display = 'block';
}

//slide images by clicking bullets


//called startslide function
startSlide();
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

li, a{
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration-line: none;
    color: black;
}

/*main-menu*/
#main-menu {
    position: relative;
}

#main-menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#main-menu li {
    display: inline-block;
}

#main-menu a {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid;
    text-align: center;
}

/*sub-topics*/
#sub-topics {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
}

#sub-topics ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#sub-topics li {
    display: block;
}

#subTopics a {
    text-align: left;
}

/*columns*/
#column1, #column2, #column3 {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: 125px;
    margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
}

/*hover underline*/
#main-menu li:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

/*slideshow*/
#slideshow {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#slide1 {
    background-image: url(https://preview.ibb.co/mV3TR7/1.jpg);
}

#slide2 {
    background-image: url(https://preview.ibb.co/bSCBeS/2.jpg);
}

#slide3 {
    background-image: url(https://preview.ibb.co/kgG9Yn/3.jpg);
}

.slide {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 800px 400px;
    width: 800px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.slide-contain {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 50%;
    transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
    text-align: center;
}

.slide-contain span {
    color: white;
}

/*arrow*/
.arrow {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 200px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
}

.arrow:hover {
    background-color: #e0dede;
    transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

/*arrow-left*/
#arrow-left {
    position: absolute;
    border-width: 30px 40px 30px 0px;
    border-color: transparent gray transparent transparent;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 300px;
}

/*arrow-right*/
#arrow-right {
    border-width: 30px 0px 30px 40px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent gray;
    right: 0;
    margin-right: 300px;
}

/*bullets*/
#slidebullet {
    position: relative;
    top: -30px;
    text-align: center;
}

.bullets {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: gray;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.bullets:hover {
    background-color: #e0dede;
}

.clicked {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <header></header>
    <nav>
        <div id="main-menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Logo</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="" id="mainTopics">Topics</a>
                    <div id="sub-topics">
                        <div id="column1" class="columns">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="">example1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">example2</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div id="slideshow">

        <div id="arrow-left" class="arrow"></div>

        <div id="slide1" class="slide">
            <div class="slide-contain">
                <span>Image One</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="slide2" class="slide">
            <div class="slide-contain">
                <span>Image Two</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="slide3" class="slide">
            <div class="slide-contain">
                <span>Image Three</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="slidebullet">
            <div id="bullet1" class="bullets"></div>
            <div id="bullet2" class="bullets"></div>
            <div id="bullet3" class="bullets"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="arrow-right" class="arrow"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <script>

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the code snippet below. I edited your code. But note that slider can be more functional.

```js
var sliderImages = document.querySelectorAll( '.slide' ),
    arrowLeft = document.querySelector( '#arrow-left' ),
    arrowRight = document.querySelector( '#arrow-right' ),
    arrowSlide = document.querySelectorAll( '.arrow' ),
    sliderBullets = document.querySelectorAll( '.bullets' ),
    current = 0;

//reset slideimages
function resetSlide() {
    for (var i = 0; i < sliderImages.length; i++) {
        sliderImages[ i ].style.display = 'none';
        sliderImages[ i ].classList.remove( 'slide-fadein' );
        sliderBullets[ i ].classList.remove( 'bullets-show' )
    }
}

//slide left
arrowLeft.addEventListener('click', function () {
    resetSlide();
    if (current === 0) {
        current = sliderImages.length;
    }

    current--;
    sliderImages[ current ].style.display = 'block';
    sliderImages[ current ].classList.add( 'slide-fadein' );
    sliderBullets[ current ].classList.add( 'bullets-show' )
});

//slide right
arrowRight.addEventListener('click', function () {
    resetSlide();
    if (current === sliderImages.length - 1) {
        current = -1;
    }

    current++;
    sliderImages[ current ].style.display = 'block';
    sliderImages[ current ].classList.add( 'slide-fadein' );
    sliderBullets[ current ].classList.add( 'bullets-show' )
});

//start slide
function startSlide() {
    sliderImages[ 0 ].style.display = 'block';
    sliderImages[ 0 ].classList.add( 'slide-fadein' );
    sliderBullets[ 0 ].classList.add( 'bullets-show' );

    setInterval( function () {
        arrowRight.click();
        sliderBullets[ current ].classList.add( 'bullets-show' )
    }, 5000 )
}

//slide images by clicking bullets
for ( let i = 0; i < sliderBullets.length; i++ ) {
    sliderBullets[ i ].addEventListener( 'click', function () {
        resetSlide();
        sliderImages[ i ].style.display = 'block';
        sliderImages[ i ].classList.add( 'slide-fadein' );
        sliderBullets[ i ].classList.add( 'bullets-show' );
        current = i
    });
}

//called startslide function
startSlide();
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0
}
#slideshow {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}
#slide1 {
    background-image: url(https://preview.ibb.co/mV3TR7/1.jpg)
}
#slide2 {
    background-image: url(https://preview.ibb.co/bSCBeS/2.jpg)
}
#slide3 {
    background-image: url(https://preview.ibb.co/kgG9Yn/3.jpg)
}
.slide {
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 800px 400px;
    width: 800px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 40px
}
.slide-fadein {
    -webkit-animation: myfadein 500ms forwards;
       -moz-animation: myfadein 500ms forwards;
         -o-animation: myfadein 500ms forwards;
            animation: myfadein 500ms forwards
}
.slide-contain {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 50%;
    font-size: 3em;
    transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
    text-align: center
}
.slide-contain span {
    color: white
}
.arrow {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 185px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    opacity: .5;
    transition: all 0.3s ease
}
.arrow:hover {
    opacity: 1
}
#arrow-left {
    position: absolute;
    border-width: 30px 40px 30px 0px;
    border-color: transparent gray transparent transparent;
    left: 300px
}
#arrow-left:hover {
    transform: translateX(-5px)
}
#arrow-right {
    border-width: 30px 0px 30px 40px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent gray;
    right: 300px
}
#arrow-right:hover {
    transform: translateX(5px)
}
#slidebullet {
    position: relative;
    top: -30px;
    text-align: center
}
.bullets {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: gray;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.5s ease
}
.bullets:hover {
    background-color: #e0dede
}
.bullets-show {
    background-color: #f00;
    -webkit-animation: boing 500ms forwards;
       -moz-animation: boing 500ms forwards;
         -o-animation: boing 500ms forwards;
            animation: boing 500ms forwards
}
@keyframes boing {
    0% { transform: scale(1.2) }
    40% { transform: scale(.6) }
    60% { transform: scale(1.2) }
    80% { transform: scale(.8) }
    100% { transform: scale(1) }
}
@keyframes myfadein {
    0% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 1 }
}
```

```html
<div id="slideshow">
    <div id="slide1" class="slide">
        <div class="slide-contain">
            <span>Image One</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="slide2" class="slide">
        <div class="slide-contain">
            <span>Image Two</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="slide3" class="slide">
        <div class="slide-contain">
            <span>Image Three</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="slidebullet">
        <div id="bullet1" class="bullets"></div>
        <div id="bullet2" class="bullets"></div>
        <div id="bullet3" class="bullets"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="arrow-left" class="arrow"></div>
    <div id="arrow-right" class="arrow"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To color proper 'bullet' in your navigation you could simply loop through all of them every time the slide changes. 
So you could write a function like this:

```
function colorBullets(){ 
    sliderBullets.forEach( bullet => {
      if(bullet.getAttribute("id").slice(-1) === current){ //First we check if lastletter of your id matches the current slide. For that to work your bullet ids should start with 0 - bullet0, bullet1 and so on. (because your current slide counter starts with 0 too)
          bullet.classList.add("clicked"); //if it matches the current slide we add our class.  
        } else {
          bullet.classList.remove("clicked"); // we remove the class from every other bullet so that at one time only one is highlighted. 
        }
      });
 }
```

And fire it every time you change a slide.

Read the comments carefully to understand how it works. .slice(-1) is used to find the last character in string. Also read up on arrow functions if the code confuses you.

For auto-slider you should basically put the code like you have for your slide-left or slide-right button inside **setInterval**, which will fire your method every X seconds. Read up on set interval function and you will get it in no time, because it's a rather simple concept. (you can start here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

Let me know if something is not clear for you :)

Comment: I'm actually avoiding w3school as much as i can,but thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: Yeah, I can understand why, but actually for setInterval it's quite ok. Gives u all the info you need to start digging deeper. Anyway - good luck with your website!

Comment: Hi,devHem may i know why did you use "id" if(bullet.getAttribute("id") the word of "id" what "id" refer to ?

Comment: Sorry I was away for few days. it refers to your divs, which have an id - <div id="bullet1"> and so on.